# Kernel panic related to DirtyJetsamMemoryLimit?

Tags: crash, launchd, kernel-panic, reboot

I've been having random crashes (freezes or kernel panics requiring hard reboots) but I can't seem to pin down the cause. Looking in Console.app on restart, the only common factor seems to be related to launchd with this message:

```
The _DirtyJetsamMemoryLimit key is not available on this platform.
```

Not sure if the crash is related to this or if it's just a coincidence. Does anyone have any ideas what might be causing this? It's driving me crazy! Thanks.

(Computer is a MacBook Pro Retina 2012, 16 GB RAM, running latest version of Yosemite. Has recently been serviced so should be absolutely fine with respect to hardware.)

Comment: I see that on a non-crashing machine - idk if it's relevant

Comment: I have two crashy machines, both of which report that. I've suspected that some combo of installed software is causing it, but I've had some issues since the late days of Mavericks. How long and how frequently have you been having issues? My machines crash every couple of weeks, usually by launchservicesd exploding to tens of GB of RAM, rendering the system useless. Any similarities?

Comment: @DustinWheeler I'll keep an eye out for launchservicesd. Crash hasn't happened since I posted this, but will be updating it next time it does. I don't have anything 'exotic' installed (no custom kexts, no virtualisation software etc.) so I have no idea what could be causing such a 'violent' crash.